# Python list comprehension over arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays and I'm trying to create a new list with all the elements of the original list, except one. I have the following code:

```
for i in xrange(FOLDS):
    #fold_sample_sets and fold_sample_labels are a list of 10 numpy arrays.
    training_samples = [s for s in fold_sample_sets if fold_sample_sets.index(s) != i]
    training_labels = [l for l in fold_label_sets if fold_label_sets.index(l) != i]
```

I've tried this with small examples in the interpreter and it's seemed to work. But here I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array slicing,

```
for i in range(FOLDS):
    # omit set #i from the list
    training_samples = fold_sample_sets[:i] + fold_sample_sets[i+1:]
    training_labels  = fold_label_sets [:i] + fold_label_sets [i+1:]
```

Comment: This works, but I'm still curious as to why I'm getting that error hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

In your comprehensions you have:

```
if fold_sample_sets.index(s) != i
```

The condition for an `if` has to be True/False.  Typically this ValueError is produced when the condition is an array with more than one element.  For example:

```
if np.array([True,False]):
    print(1)
```

Is this condition True, or is it False?  Or is it both?  Should it print 1 or not?

The error is suggesting that you use `np.any` or `np.all` to reduce the multiple values down to one.  The alternative is to make sure that you are not applying the logical operator to a multiple element array.

What is `fold_sample_sets.index(s) != i` (for a typical value of `s`)?

---

```
sets = [np.ones((2,2))*i for i in range(5)]
[s for s in sets if sets.index(s)!=3]  # this error
sets.index(s)   # same error
```

Looks like list `.index` does not work with array elements.  To calculate this index, Python compares `s` with each element in `sets`.  When we compare one list with another, `[1,2]==[3,4]`, we get a simple boolean, `False`.  But when we compare one array with another we get another array: `np.array([1,2])==np.array([3,4])`, `array([False, False], dtype=bool)`.  That's where the ambiguity arises.

A better way of doing the same comprehension (without this `.index`) is:

```
[s for j,s in enumerate(sets) if j!=i]
```

Comment: From the python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) fold_sample_sets.index(s) should be the index of s in the list fold_sample_sets. It shouldn't ever be a boolean.

Comment: On further testing I find that `.index(s)` does not work with arrays.  See my edits.